# How to integrate fraction of y with respect to x

Tags: integration

How would i go about to integrate the following expression:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{(-y+a)^2}$$

Comment: [Separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Ordinary_differential_equations_.28ODE.29)?

Comment: It is $(a-y)^2dy=dx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$\int (-y+a)^2dy=-\frac{(-y+a)^3}{3}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y'(x)=\frac{1}{\left(\text{a}-y(x)\right)^2}\Longleftrightarrow\int y'(x)\left(\text{a}-y(x)\right)^2\space\text{d}x=\int1\space\text{d}x$$

Use:

1. Substitute $u=y(x)$ and $\text{d}u=y'(x)\space\text{d}x$, after that substitute $\text{s}=\text{a}-u$ and $\text{d}\text{s}=-\text{d}u$:
   $$\int y'(x)\left(\text{a}-y(x)\right)^2\space\text{d}x=\int\left(\text{a}-u\right)^2\space\text{d}u=-\int\text{s}^2\space\text{d}s=\text{C}-\frac{\left(\text{a}-y(x)\right)^3}{3}$$
2. $$\int1\space\text{d}x=x+\text{C}$$

So:

$$-\frac{\left(\text{a}-y(x)\right)^3}{3}=x+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow\left(\text{a}-y(x)\right)^3=\text{C}-3x$$